# Draw Horizontal/Vertical line in pdf on a specific page using iTextSharp in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I'm trying to draw a horizontal/Vertical line in pdf on a specific page number(let say on page number 3 out of 8 pages). But, I'm only able to draw a line on the first and last page.

Here's my code:

**Step 1:**

```
public ActionResult CreatePDF(string id)
    {
        // Create the iTextSharp document.
        Document doc = new Document();

        // Set the document to write to memory.
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memStream);
        writer.CloseStream = false;
        doc.Open();
        
        DrawThickLine(writer, 36f, 519f, 806f, 519f);//Horizontal Line
    
        DrawThickLine(writer, 36f, 280f, 36f, 521f);//Vertical Line
    
        // Close and get the resulted binary data.
        doc.Close();
        
        // Send the binary data to the browser.          
        return BinaryContentData(memStream, "", "", d1.formnumber.Value);//External Binary Content method
    }
```

**Step 2:**

```
private static void DrawThickLine(PdfWriter writer, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
    {
        PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
        contentByte.SetLineWidth(4.0f);   // Make a bit thicker than 1.0 default
        contentByte.SetColorStroke(Color.BLACK);
        contentByte.MoveTo(x1, y1);
        contentByte.LineTo(x2, y2);
        contentByte.Stroke();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

After working an hour, here's my solution.

**Step 1:**

```
public ActionResult CreatePDF(string id)
{
    // Create the iTextSharp document.
    Document doc = new Document();

    // Set the document to write to memory.
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memStream);
    writer.CloseStream = false;
    doc.Open();
    
   // DrawThickLine(writer, 36f, 519f, 806f, 519f);//Horizontal Line

   // DrawThickLine(writer, 36f, 280f, 36f, 521f);//Vertical Line

    // Close and get the resulted binary data.
    doc.Close();
    
    // Send the binary data to the browser.          
    return BinaryContentData(memStream, "", "", id);//External Binary Content method
}
```

**Step 2:**

```
 protected ActionResult BinaryContentData(MemoryStream pdf, string UserPwd, string OwnerPwd, string uid)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);

        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();

        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
        pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
        
        for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= reader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++)
        {
            if (pageIndex == 3)//Page 3
            {
                DrawThickLine(pdfStamper, pageIndex, 36f, 519f, 806f, 519f);//Horizontal Line
                DrawThickLine(pdfStamper, pageIndex, 36f, 280f, 36f, 521f);//Vertical Line
            }
        }
        ............//some code goes here
        return new BinaryContentResult(buffer, "application/pdf", uid);
    }
```

**Step 3:**

```
private static void DrawThickLine(PdfStamper pdfStamper, int pageIndex, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
    {
        PdfContentByte cb = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageIndex);
        cb.SetLineWidth(4.0f);   // Make a bit thicker than 1.0 default
        cb.SetColorStroke(Color.BLACK);
        cb.MoveTo(x1, y1);
        cb.LineTo(x2, y2);
        cb.Stroke();
    }
```